# Extending the Cart page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

The cart page located in `/system/library/` holds all the control for calculation and the further proceedings in the cart and checkout.

As I am changing the system to make it work differently, I need to write some code in the system file i.e. Cart.php.

So I want to extend this cart page so that I can hold my newly created functions there. How can I do it. Or is there any other way to keep the new functions.

Comment: After having looked at and around the cart logic and having made sure there is no way to inject your own logic (please make sure!) then you'll most probably have to do this with [vQmod](http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/vQmod) due to how inflexible OpenCart is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best bet is to write down Your own class, e.g. `/system/library/my_cart.php` that will extend from the original class, like this:

```
class MyCart extends Cart {
    // ...
}
```

Here You can place all Your new functions, new stuff, make overrides to functions from Cart class, etc.

Then, in `index.php` make sure to add:

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/my_cart.php');
```

after

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/cart.php');
```

and to change

```
$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));
```

to this

```
$registry->set('cart', new MyCart($registry));
```

That should be it...

But if You do not want to overwrite either the `index.php`, then the last option is using vQmod...